# I can't run my project AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: xml

I can't run my project, this is my first error, please help

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_size">56dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_size_small">34dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_size_small_padding">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_half">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_medium">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_small">14sp</dimen>
**`<item name="touchId" type="id">2564</item> `**              
<string name="app_name">Vidsta Video Player</string>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

I can't run my project, this is my first error, please help